# Choosing right Model exchange rate

Tags: r, time-series, arima, fitting, white-noise

I have obtained these two plots using R, I have to fit a model and the trouble is choosing between an ARMA(0,0), and an AR3. The main issue is the autocorrelation at lag 3, is it enough significant to be considered in the analysis? The BIC of the two models is very similar. Moreover Residuals are good for both models, altough AR3 removes the little correlation at lag 3 in the residuals ACF.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer.

First of all, an ARMA(0,0) is a white noise process. I dont know the purpose of your work, but white noise is a model with no predictability.

On the other hand, you need to model the statistically significant lag 3 (i assume it is). Perhaps AR(3) or MA(3). Consider both models and then decide based on AIC or BIC.

Comment: Ok. I took the first difference to obtain stationarity. So, I can't make prediction if I suppose a white noise process? The aim is the prediction after a good fitting. If is not an AR3, what model do you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: The prediction that I obtain supposing a WN is quite similar to the MA(10). The order of 10 is not to high, according to parsimony criteria?

Comment: Here they are : https://ibb.co/eP5CLn (data comes from eur/usd closing exchange rates)

Comment: thanks for the useful article. Unfortunately I have not the strong correlation at lag 1, but only the third weak lag. If I suppose an ARMA(0,0), the starting series was a random walk. In the article they said that it can be suitable. Seasonality is not so strong, do you conferm?

Comment: looking at these graph of squared residuals, do you think a GARCH is necessary?  https://ibb.co/dOgdbS  Thanks

Comment: so according to you I need to add an arch. But why the all the p-values in Mcleod Li test are above the dashed line?